# Bootstrap confirm Dialog not working properly while invoked by server button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, bootstrap-dialog

I'm trying to invoke a **BootstrapDialog.confirm()** by **asp:LinkButton** on a **custom SharePoint WebPart** this way:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="BootstrapDialogPopup(this);return false;" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

And **BootstrapDialog** function is:

```
function BootstrapDialogPopup(param) {
BootstrapDialog.confirm({
    title: 'Cancel',
    message: 'Are you sure?!',
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DEFAULT,
    closable: true,
    draggable: true,
    btnCancelLabel: 'Cancel',
    btnOKLabel: 'Ok',
    btnOKClass: 'btn-warning',
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            javascript: __doPostBack(param.name, '');
        } else {
            BootstrapDialog.closeAll();
        }
    }
});
```

}

But, once i clicked on **asp:LinkButton** its server side click event(**btn_Click**) get called before i get the chance to choose '**Ok**' or '**Cancel**'.

> So, My question is: How to hold the Button server event until i get
>   the chance to choose'**Ok**' or '**Cancel**'.

Please note that this issue occurs only on **SharePoint environment**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent LinkButton post back OnClientClick not working. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710561/prevent-linkbutton-post-back-onclientclick-not-working-why)

Comment: @mjwills, i couldn't find an answer on the provided link, thanks.

Comment: Did you try OnClientClick="BootstrapDialogPopup(this);return false;"

Comment: did you try changing your `BootstrapDialogPopup()` javascript function to `return false;`? This is how the linked article does it (and similar to Hany Habib's comment above)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087883/bootstrap-dialog-confirmation-onclick-confirmation-event help?

Comment: @mjwills nope, not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem as mentioned that the link button is posting back, this is due to that your method BootstrapDialogPopup doesnt have return false at the end. So you have 2 choices:

1) Add`return false;`at the end of `BootstrapDialogPopup()`

2) Modify Your Button OnClientClick to be : `OnClientClick="BootstrapDialogPopup(this);return false;"`

Comment: I tried the above options, unfortunately server side event never gets called in both cases

Comment: Update the final code version and will make it work togther

Comment: Please find the updated version in the asp:LinkButton section.

Comment: Great.. now after you click the linkbutton can you check the value of variable _spFormOnSubmitCalled in the console? Is it true or false

Comment: _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false

Comment: Ok perfect one more thing check the network tab is any request sent to sever with correct __dopostback args ? Or nothing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172793/discussion-between-hany-habib-and-null).